# IronPython (for .NET 4.x) integration with Unity

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, ironpython

I am trying to integrate a python script with my Unity application using Visual Studio 2017. I have followed all the steps given in the various online tutorials, and this is my code:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuSlv.jpg)

Also, when I go to the Unity inspector, this is the error seen when I select the dll (saved in Assets/Editor/plugins/resources directory): [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzPvF.jpg)
I have installed the latest version of IronPython which states that it is compatible with .NET 4.x as well as 3.5.

Could someone please suggest a fix for this, or some other alternative to use for Python integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that your editor is incompatible with the .NET version you are using. You may wish to update your path to include both the .NET 3.5 and 4.0 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Unity includes an experimental runtime version that supports .NET 4.6, but it is not the default.  To select this choose `Edit`->`Project Settings`->`Player`.  Then in the Inspector Window scroll down to `Other Settings`->`Configuration`->`Scripting Runtime Version`.  Select `Experimental (.NET 4.6 Equivalent)` from the menu.